# Creating a Wordpress Header

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

Hello guys and girls,

I've been given my first WordPress build at work, with freedom on pretty much anything. I chose to use Altitude pro as a theme with Genesis as a framework.

I love the theme but, for a service page the theme is not exactly fantastic. To spice it up a bit, I'd like to create a custom header design for every service page on the site.

This would be a coloured background over the top 1000px of the page or so, that has a solid colour with some patterns on top.

Due to my inexperience though, I'm not really sure on how to do it and my PHP knowledge is not fantastic.

Could anyone please assist?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can check here for normal headers or even fixed headers. They explain well. http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_navbar.asp

Comment: _Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline._

Comment: Okey my friend.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code that makes a fixed header with menus. If you don't want to make it fixed you can just delete "position: fixed;".

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {margin:0;}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: #111;
}

.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<ul>
  <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>

<div style="padding:20px;margin-top:30px;background-color:#1abc9c;height:1500px;">
<h1>Fixed Top Navigation Bar</h1>
<h2>Scroll this page to see the effect</h2>
<h2>The navigation bar will stay at the top of the page while scrolling</h2>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```